# Overriding the upload plugin in Strapi

Tags: typescript, strapi

I'm trying to override the upload plugin in Strapi to only allow the upload of images, and reject all other file types with appropriate error messages.
I wanted to display a console message as a start to say whether the file is an image or not, but I'm getting a runtime error whenever I try to upload anything in the Media Library saying: "*this.enhanceAndValidateFile is not a function*".

Here is the code - I copied the exact code of the `enhanceAndValidateFile` function from [Strapi's source code](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/main/packages/core/upload/server/services/upload.js#L167), and only added a *console.log* after checking the file type.

src/Index.ts:

```js
  register({ strapi }) {

    strapi.services["plugin::upload.upload"].enhanceAndValidateFile =
    require("./extensions/upload/overrides").enhanceAndValidateFile;
  },
```

src/extensions/upload/overrides.ts:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const { extension } = require("mime-types");
const {
    sanitize,
    nameToSlug,
    contentTypes: contentTypesUtils,
    errors: { ApplicationError, NotFoundError },
    file: { bytesToKbytes },
  } = require('@strapi/utils');

module.exports = ({strapi}) => ({ async enhanceAndValidateFile(file, fileInfo = {}, metas = {}) {
    const currentFile = await strapi.formatFileInfo(
      {
        filename: file.name,
        type: file.type,
        size: file.size,
      },
      fileInfo,
      {
        ...metas,
        tmpWorkingDirectory: file.tmpWorkingDirectory,
      }
    );
    currentFile.getStream = () => fs.createReadStream(file.path);

    const { optimize, isImage, isFaultyImage, isOptimizableImage } = strapi
      .plugin('upload')
      .service('image-manipulation');

    if (await isImage(currentFile)) {
        console.log("Yes it is an image");
      if (await isFaultyImage(currentFile)) {
        throw new ApplicationError('File is not a valid image');
      }
      if (await isOptimizableImage(currentFile)) {
        return optimize(currentFile);
      }
    }
    console.log("No it is not an image");
    return currentFile;
},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The type exported from overrides.ts does not match to what is required in index.ts, thus it can't found enhanceAndValidateFile(). Besides, formatFileInfo() is not a member of the strapi instance.

src/extensions/upload/overrides.ts:

```
module.exports = {
  async enhanceAndValidateFile(file, fileInfo = {}, metas = {}) {
      const currentFile = await strapi
         .plugin('upload')
         .service('upload')
         .formatFileInfo(...);
      ...
  }
}
```